# Zipping folders in powershell

Tags: powershell, zip

Hope fellow scripters can help with this one :) Been breaking my head around the problem for few hours now.

I'm trying to zip up certain folders using powershell.
My folder structure is

Backups
BoxIntranet
Components
Content
Database
Exec
Files
Logs
Multibrowser
Multibrowser\Legacy\Customisation
Packages
ParentPortal
ParentPortal\customisation
StudentPortal
StudentPortal\customisation
Update
WebDav

There are a lot more files and folders in every one of the above but these are the ones I'm mainly interested in.
I am trying to zip it all up using either Write-Zip or Compress-Archive methods in PowerShell but my conditions are.

1. Only Content, Files, Database folders should be zipped from root
2. Multibrowser\Legacy\customisation, StudentPortal\Customisation and ParentPortal\customisation folders should also be backed up.
3. Folder structure should remain the same in the zip file meaning that Root of the zip file should have Content, Files, Database, Multibrowser, ParentPortal and StudentPortal folders. Whilst Content, Files and Database folders should have everything zipped up, Multibrowser, ParentPortal and StudentPortal folders should only have the specified sub directories and all files within them.

Code:

```
$FilesAndInclude = @("Content", "Files", "Database", "Multibrowser\Legacy\customisation", 
                     "StudentPortal\customisation", "ParentPortal\customisation", 
                     "BoxIntranet\customisation")
$FilesToExclude = @("connectionstrings.config", "inc_dbconn.asp")
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Folder" -Include $FilesAndInclude -Recurse -Exclude $FilesToExclude|
    Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "Archive.zip"
```

I've tried the above and it doesn't do anything however if I remove the -Include parameter then it zips up everything however doesn't retain folder structure.

Is there any way to complete what I am after within powershell?

Comment: What does "doesn't do anything" mean? Is there one or more error messages? Is an Archive.zip file created? Is the output of Get-ChildItem the file and directory names you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first things first, the reason that you are having a hard time using the `-Include` parameter is because it is designed to exclusively include only the things you specify. As such, it will look at the name of things (not their path), and check against the list and if it matches something in the list it will include that item. Since you only list folder names it is only including those folders (*but not their contents*). So you aren't getting any files passed down the pipe this way. To get around that you'll need to build your file list first, then pipe it to the cmdlet to zip things up.

Next issue is that `Compress-Archive` doesn't store path info, so you'll need to use `Write-Zip`. I have included what I think you would want for that cmdlet.

```
$FilesAndInclude = @("Content", "Files", "Database", "Multibrowser\Legacy\customisation", 
                     "StudentPortal\customisation", "ParentPortal\customisation", 
                     "BoxIntranet\customisation")
$FilesToExclude = @("connectionstrings.config", "inc_dbconn.asp")
[array]$FilesToZip = Get-ChildItem .\* -Exclude $FilesToExclude -File
$FilesToZip += $FilesAndInclude | ForEach{Get-ChildItem .\$_ -Exclude $FilesToExclude -File}
$FilesToZip | Write-Zip -EntryPathRoot $(Resolve-Path .\|Select -Expand Path) -OutputPath Archive.zip
```

Comment: You are a star. This code didn't do exactly what I wanted however it did gave me a very good starting point. This has done the job for me :)